# Time for AJAX request is very inconsistent

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using AJAX with jQuery and making requests to a PHP server. The time that my AJAX requests  takes is very inconsistent. Usually it takes about 100-250ms, but then sometimes it even goes up to about 800 ms, and 1-3 seconds is not too unusual either (also got one that took 11  seconds). Speed is crucial for my application, and therefor I can only accept 800ms or less. Is there anything that can be done? I'm running my application on a web hotel (shared host), which might be the problem(?)

Comment: if it's real time use websocket, if not download all your data at once instead of multiplying ajax request. you have no control over the time needed by a http request to reach a server ./

Comment: @mikakun Websockets would great for this, but unfortunately it's not an option - at least not with my current server host.

Comment: -> reduce http  requests as much as possible, cache db results, send 304 every time it's possible is all u can do then

Comment: also get is faster than post

Comment: AJAX requests are as unpredictable in timing as any other normal HTTP request.

Comment: @mikakun Hm okay, but isn't it weird that the time it takes varries this much?

Comment: complain to your isp !